# Why does Stream.Read not use an out parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

From my understanding it seems logical that the buffer parameter of `Stream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)` should be an out parameter as the value is read into the buffer that passed in, but that is not the case.

What is the reason for this? Is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: Why should it be out? then what's the point of the offset and count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`out` is only used when the instance is *assigned* from within the method, and passed back out.  `Stream.Read` expects the buffer to have already been created by the programmer before calling the method.  The existing instance is just being passed in, where the *data* within the instance is being modified, not the reference its self.

While `out` *allows* you to pass in an existing instance, it *guarantees* that a different instance will be coming back out.  In-fact, even though it allows you to pass in an existing instance, you can't access its value from within the method.  It treats the parameter as if it were never assigned. "[CS0269 Use of unassigned out parameter 'value'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0269)"

You will get a compiler error if you don't assign something to the parameter before the method returns. "[CS0177 The out parameter 'value' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0177)"

Comment: @MatthiasBurger - It's not `ref` for the same reason, `Read` does not need to create a buffer for use by the caller.

Comment: `ref` isn't used because there is no need to use it. `Stream.Read` works directly on the existing instance.

Comment: [out parameter modifier (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) Has an example where the instance is created outside the method, going against "out is only used when the instance is created within the method and passed back out."

Comment: @bic True, but that's a bit of an edge case.   I've changed the wording in my answer from "created" to "assigned" to accommodate that though.

Comment: @BradleyUffner So it is because you may want to keep whatever bytes are already in the buffer, but making it an `out` will means whatever is in the buffer to be lost?

Comment: @bic That's one reason. Another reason is that reusing the current `buffer` instance is *far* more efficient, no need to allocate new memory, less load on the garbage collector, etc.

Answer (score 1):

the data read is put into an already specified array of bytes. `buffer` in this situation is already instantiated by the calling code and may have non-zero bytes in the array already. if it was specified as `out` then the Read method would be creating a buffer, and returning it back. In that situation `offset` and `count` would be redundant, as it's made the byte array based on its own findings, it doesn't need to know where to "fit in" its data being read.

Answer (score 1):

Making `buffer` an `out` parameter would make the API less usable, without offering any improvement in return.

Currently, a reference for the buffer is passed to the method (because arrays are reference types), and the output is written directly into the array.

Using `out` would prevent important use cases, when the buffer is external to the caller of `Stream.Read` - for example, a read-only property of some of the classes that it uses.

Moreover, there would not be much improvement in usability, because swapping the buffer from under the caller, presumably, to expand it, is not an appropriate course of action when `offset` and `count` are passed to you by the caller.